# Balanced Brackets - stack not recognized as empty

Tags: c++, stack

This is driving me a bit batty. I've spent an embarrassingly long amount of time trying to find the error and cannot. The problem is to determine whether a given input string of brackets is balanced. The input '{[()()]}' returns 0 when it should return 1. The code below is never actually reaching the return 1 part but I can't see why not - the stack should be empty by then. Any ideas?

```
#include <stack>

int solution(string &S) {

stack<char> bracketStack;
char a, b, c;

for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
    if (S[i]=='{' || S[i]=='[' || S[i]=='(') {
        bracketStack.push(S[i]);
    } else {
        switch (S[i]) {
        case ('}') :
            a = bracketStack.top();
            bracketStack.pop();
            if (a==']' || a==')') {
                return 0;
            }
        case (']') :
            b = bracketStack.top();
            bracketStack.pop();
            if (b=='}' || b==')') {
                return 0;
            }
        case (')') :
            c = bracketStack.top();
            bracketStack.pop();
            if (c==']' || c=='}') {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }    
}

if (bracketStack.empty()) {
    cout << "empty";
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: "Any ideas?" yeah. **Debug the program**. Take the time to learn how. It will save you countless hours of just staring at the code wondering why it's doing what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic has a mistake: the call

```
a = bracketStack.top(); // or b, or c
```

inside all three branches of `switch` is not protected by the check that the stack is non-empty. This will result in undefined behavior (reading from invalid element of the stack) when there are more closing brackets than opening ones.

Fixing this problem will address the issue that you are having. However, your program remains non-optimal, because the three branches look nearly identical. You can fix this by combining the switch as follows:

```
// Set up an array of matching brackets: } --> {, ] --> [, ) --> (
char match[128] = {0};
match['}'] = '{';
match[']'] = '[';
match[')'] = '(';

... // This goes inside the `for` loop
if (S[i]=='{' || S[i]=='[' || S[i]=='(') {
    bracketStack.push(S[i]);
} else {
    if (bracketStack.empty()) {
        cout << "More closing brackets than opening ones" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    a = bracketStack.top();
    bracketStack.pop();
    if (match[a] != S[i]) {
        cout << "Mismatched" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: More importantly, missing `break;` after each `case`.

Comment: The popped character is compared to closing brackets, but only opening brackets are pushed.

Comment: @melpomene is break necessary when there is a return?

Comment: @ErikM There's not always a return, though.

Comment: And indeed in any balanced set of brackets there's never a return in the switch

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you for the assistance; however, the code is still producing false for input {[()()]}.

Comment: And better to say `cout << S[i] << " mismatched" << endl;` than only to say that there's a mismatch.  :)